# How to extract content from a string (Java)

Tags: java, string, indexing, methods, substring

I was wondering how to extract a certain part of a string. For example, I am making something that requires the user to enter a date in MM/DD/YYYY or M/D/YYYY format and what I want to do is to extract the month. I see the substring method but there can be more than 1 digit for the month. Also, I have tried the indexOf but that one required an int value, not a symbol.

```
String startDateInput = "12/09/2015";

String getMonthStart = startDateInput.substring(1, indexOf("/"));
```

Comment: You were very close, just use the indexes a little differently `String getMonthStart = startDateInput.substring(0, startDateInput.indexOf('/'));`

Answer (score 4):

You could use `String#split` here:

```java
String startDateInput = "12/09/2015";
String getMonthStart = startDateInput.split("/")[0];
System.out.println(getMonthStart);  // 12
```

Or, we could use a regex replace approach:

```java
String startDateInput = "12/09/2015";
String getMonthStart = startDateInput.replaceAll("/.*$", "");
System.out.println(getMonthStart);  // 12
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to split that `String`, you can parse it to a `LocalDate` and then call `getMonth()` or `getMonthValue()` depending on your desired result (name or number of that month).

If you use the pattern `"M/d/uuuu"` or `"M/d/yyyy"` to create a `java.time.DateTimeFormatter`, it will parse `String`s like `"12/09/2015"` and `"2/9/2015"`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // provide some example date as String
    String input = "12/09/2015";
    // define a formatter that is capable of parsing such a String
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu");
    // parse it to a suitable object using the formatter
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(input, dtf);
    // extract the Month from it
    Month month = localDate.getMonth();
    // or directly get the number of that month in a year
    int monthVal = localDate.getMonthValue();
    // use the month and a desired locale to determine the month name
    String monthNameEn = month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
    // print some super meaningful example output
    System.out.println(String.format("%s is month no. %d in a year",
                                     monthNameEn, monthVal));
}
```

This outputs

```
December is month no. 12 in a year
```

This is not as short as splitting the input and extracting the number of the month, but it provides a lot more possibilities, like getting the names of months or days of week in different languages etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 String startDateInput="12/09/2015";
 String month=startDateInput.substring(0,startDateInput.indexOf('/'));
```